# How to set color as Window's highlight color?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, colors, highlight, selecteditem

As title, how?

I want to make a TextBlock when got focused, it background color will be window os's highlighted color (i.e The color when you highlight text in your internet explorer).

Is there any way I can get that color code so I can put into the style?

```
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
</Trigger>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am a little confused on what exactly you are asking for. The selected Background color or the selected Text color, and are you wanting WPF or Silverlight.  This will will give you the Highlight background brush in WPF.

Look at the [SystemColors Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx) specifically the [SystemColors.HighlightBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.highlightbrush.aspx) Property

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}" />
```

As for Silverlight take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816238/cannot-add-system-color-in-styles-in-silverlight)

Comment: +1 Thanks! Actually I meant just the selectd background.  But yea, I just notice I need both.  And I could able to found it from your referece. Thanks again!

Comment: @KingChan Glad to have been of help